# Matrix Calculation Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose, broadcasting

I am trying to calculate Rij = Aij x Bji/Cij with numPy broadcasting. Also raise an exception if  matrices are not the  same size (n × n).

I am not so sure if this is correct or if I should be doing element wise or matrix wise. could anyone tell me how to do it

```
A = [[(i+j)/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]
B = [[(i-j)/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]
C = [[((i+1)/(j+1))/2000 for i in range(500)] for j in range(500)]



def matrix_R(A,B,C):

    A1 = np.array(A)
    B1 = np.array(B)
    C1 = np.array(C)   
    eq = (A1 @ np.transpose(B1)) 
    Rij = np.divide(eq, C1)
    
    if len(A1) != len(B1) or len(A1) != len(C1):
        raise ArithmeticError('Matrices are NOT the same size.')
    return Rij
    


matrix_R(A, B, C)
```

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable without knowing whether you want element wise or matrix wise multiplication. Either could potentially be reasonable, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The @ is the matrix product operator for numpy arrays.

```
np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) @ np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

is

```
np.array([[1*5+2*7, 1*6+2*8], [3*5+4*7, 3*6+4*8]])
```

For element multiplication you may use * which does element-wise product for numpy arrays.

```
np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) * np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

is

```
np.array([[1*5, 2*6], [3*7, 4*8])
```

To answer your question, you can compute R the matrix of Rij = Aij x Bji/Cij with:

```
R = np.divide(np.multiply(A, np.transpose(B)), C)
```

or equivalently and shorter:

```
R = A * B.T / C
```